# pass by reference between processes

Tags: python

I have an object:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

class ASYNC(object):
    def __init__(self, THREADS=[]):
        print('do')
        pool = Pool(processes=len(THREADS))
        self.THREAD_POOL = {}
        thread_index = 0
        for thread_ in THREADS:
            self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index] = {
                'thread': thread_['thread'],
                'args': thread_['args'],
                'callback': thread_['callback']
            }
            self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['running'] = True
            pool.apply_async(self.run, [thread_index], callback=thread_['callback'])
            thread_index += 1
    def run(self, thread_index):
        print('enter')
        while(self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['running']):
            print("loop")
            self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['thread'](self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index])#HERE
            time.sleep(1)
        self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['running'] = False
    def wait_for_finish(self):
        for pool in self.THREAD_POOL:
            while(self.THREAD_POOL[pool]['running']):
                print("sleep" + str(self.THREAD_POOL[pool]['running']))
                time.sleep(1)
def x(pool):#HERE
    print(str(pool))
    if(pool['args'][0] >= 15):
        pool['running'] = False
    pool['args'][0] += 1


def y(str):
    print("done")

A = ASYNC([{'thread': x, 'args':[10], 'callback':y}])

print("start")
A.wait_for_finish()
```

I am having issues passing `self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]` as reference to `def x(pool)`

I need `x(pool)` to change the value of the variable in the object.

If i check the value in wait_for_finish then the object is not changed.

Passing object by reference: (tested and works properly)

```
x = {"1":"one", "2","two"}
def test(a):
     a["1"] = "ONE"
print(x["1"])#outputs ONE as expected
```

this means that dictionaries in python are passed by reference; So, why in my code is it passing by value?

---

### SOLUTION

@DevShark

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

according to the documentation, you should not do this unless absolutely needed. I decided not to use this. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue

### instead i will be doing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

class ASYNC(object):
    def __init__(self, THREADS=[]):
        print('do')
        pool = Pool(processes=len(THREADS))
        self.THREAD_POOL = {}
        thread_index = 0
        for thread_ in THREADS:
            self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index] = {
                'thread': thread_['thread'],
                'args': thread_['args'],
                'callback': thread_['callback']
            }
            self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['running'] = True
            pool.apply_async(self.run, [thread_index], callback=thread_['callback'])
            thread_index += 1
    def run(self, thread_index):
        print('enter')
        while(self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['running']):
            print("loop")
            self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['thread'](thread_index)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.THREAD_POOL[thread_index]['running'] = False
    def wait_for_finish(self):
        for pool in self.THREAD_POOL:
            while(self.THREAD_POOL[pool]['running']):
                print("sleep" + str(self.THREAD_POOL[pool]['running']))
                time.sleep(1)
def x(index):
    global A
    A.THREAD_POOL[index]
    print(str(pool))
    if(pool['args'][0] >= 15):
        pool['running'] = False
    pool['args'][0] += 1


def y(str):
    print("done")

A = ASYNC([{'thread': x, 'args':[10], 'callback':y}])

print("start")
A.wait_for_finish()
```

Comment: Why the down vote? so i can update question.

Comment: Could this be because i am using multiprocessing? Should i just make my A object a global and access the variable i need inside the method?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but the code seems to be rather "complicated". Can you simplify the code so that it still shows the problematic behavior?

Comment: I think this problem is specific to this code, and i don't know why.

Comment: Instead i will post a code sample that works, that is pretty much the same as this code sample. give me a moment.

Comment: It's definitely because of multiprocessing. Your `x` function will be executed in a separate process, so changing `pool` there won't affect the parent process, you should have a look at the [docs about sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Also, are you sure what you're trying to do isn't already provided by the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module?

Comment: Just to be clear, my answer was not suggesting to do it using the list directly. I just added that point to (try to) be clear and exhaustive. On the contrary, I added the link to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your function in a different process. That's the way multiprocessing works. Therefore it does not matter what you do with the object, modifications will not be seen in other processes.

To share data between process, see [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) as someone noted in a comment.

> Data can be stored in a shared memory map using Value or Array.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. @VincentSavard just fixed it.